# How to show all products at home page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How to show all product details (price,description,image..) at home page,

Using Below Coding in Cms->Home page ->Content,

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Its not showing any product in Front end?

check that cms Home page Design,

```
<\!--<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
    <block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
<reference name="right">
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
</reference>-->
```

Its Coding in comment in html tag and remove that html tag it will show products,but it show products image like below, Products showing once user viewed that products it will show,Why it showing recently user viewed products,I want to show all products.

[Home Page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKhLS.png)

Comment: `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` this should give you product list, The comment code is fetching recent products that's why it's showing you recent products.

Comment: {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}} in these code not showing all product at home page why?

Answer (score 0):

use this code with the root category id because without category id it can not be list products.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

and make category 'Is Anchor' yes

Comment: No not showing products in front end. what is type mean catalog/product_list ?it denote controller and view?

Comment: are you using category id and make you all category Is Anchor yes ?

Comment: yes add category id ana all category Anchor yes only

Comment: this is working on my end
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="2" name="home.catalog.product.list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}

Comment: type="catalog/product_list" plz tell me catelog denote what and product_list denote what?,thanx for your reply

Comment: app->code->core->Mage->Catalog->Block ,inside i cant find Product list file.

Anything wrong in my search?Sorry for my silly question am new to magento.

Comment: here will be  `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/product/list.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

If you want this to work on Magento 1.9.2.2 (also 1.9.2.3 and 1.9.2.4) and higher you'll need to add block catalog/product_list to System > Permissions > Blocks and set Allowed to Yes.